# Too many login options and too many different accounts

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts

Is there any reason why we can't just have one set of login details, to get into one account, to access all Stack Exchange sites?  I often go away from the site simply because I can't be bothered to log in to do whatever it was I came there for.

This isn't helped by the fact that I can't use my normal password here, so I had to add a couple of characters to it and I can't remember what they were.  I don't care that much if someone else gets access to my Stack Exchange account, so the restrictions seem a bit over the top - people who want to use secure passwords can use them; I'd rather not be forced into it for something as trivial as a question and answer site.

Comment: what makes you think you can't? I certainly do. I sometimes need to log in to that single account multiple times, site by site, but it's the same underlying account at my OpenID provider.

Comment: I use my Google account to auth, and it does just this. I log in once, and any time I visit another SE site I am logged in automatically.

Comment: You do know you can also log in with Google, Facebook, Yahoo, etc., right? And if you use the same machine and store cookies, it automatically logs you in unless you weren't on the site for quite a while. I honestly don't think I've typed in my password more than 5 times this year, if that many, and I use 2 different machines.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we are talking about per-site here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please. From a user experience point of view, it's quite annoying to realize that I wanted to upvote something, realizing that I can't and then go through the sign-up process, just to upvote something.

If we don't want to join all the sites or just have one network account, have a 'Join Site' button at the top if people are logged in to their SE account already, which joins the site (and refreshes the page?), maybe even right next to the sign up button.